# Quickly reduced resting pulse after few cardio sessions

Tags: heart-rate

Preample: this is a academic question about the link between aerobic activity and the neurotransmitters controlling the heart rate. I am using my own observations as the starting point but not asking for medical advice in any way. If I was in any way nervous about my health I would ask my doctor, not an online forum.

I am an 46 year old male. 189 cm and 89 kg. Average fit, no smoking, very little alcohol.

Years ago I was into cycling, long rides but not overly fast, probably perfect cardio. For the last ten years the yearly xcountry skiing holiday has probably been the largest physiological event for my body and I have noticed a reduction in my resting heart rate in the week/months after.

This year it was cut short and I only had four days of 2-3 hours of skiing. But I have also have a garmin watch this time and have registered my heart rate reduction. It went from a daily low of @62 to @47 now a week after the holiday. My average pulse while skiing was 150-160 so somewhat high. But even then only four days should not have such an impact, no? My guess it is not a real reflection of change of fitness but perhaps something to do with neurotransmitters?

Anyone able to shed some light on the mechanics?

Comment: Even if we agree it's academic curiosity, there are two more ways in which this is off topic.: 1) it lacks prior research, and 2) answers would necessarily be speculative and opinion-based. You might consider trying this question on Fitness.SE.